# How can I use JQuery so that when a user clicks on this, a sudden color appears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<a href="/list" onclick="????">
    <div>
LOTS OF INFO HERE
LOTS OF INFO HERE
LOTS OF INFO HERE
LOTS OF INFO HERE
    </div>
</a>
```

I have a div, which is inside a hyperlink.  The whole div is clickable.
When the user clicks on this big div, I would like the entire div to turn light blue, and then slowly fade into white. This will give the user a feeling that he's clicking it!

Thanks.

Comment: Placing a block level element (div) inside an inline element (a) is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't need the div within the anchor for this.

I would use jQuery's [Color Animations](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin for this. From [this page](http://dev.jquery.com/~john/ticket/fx-rewrite2/), click the "Animate Boxes" button to see the effect you mentioned.

Once you have that plugin referenced, the syntax is rather simple:

```
$(".myDiv").click(function(){
  $(this).stop()
    .css("background-color", "blue").animate({"background-color":"white"}, 3000);
});
```

```
<div class="myDiv">click me to make the magic happen</div>
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/ohire/2 (click the text)

Answer (score 0):

the div inside the anchor is bad markup.
if the background is white you could also animate opacity.
if I were creating this effect I would animate it to blue then back to white on the callback. it gives a good timing effect opposed to instant in your face blue then white....try like 500 in on speed or so and 4000 out.